# ggplot2: Add additional guide for diamond shaped ppints

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
groups = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5))
scores = c(seq(1,5),seq(1,5),seq(1,5))
times1 = rnorm(15, mean = 3 , sd = 2)
times2 = rnorm(15, mean = 1 , sd = 0.5)
df = data.frame(groups,scores, times1,times2)
```

and I have the following plot

```
df = data.frame(groups,scores, times1,times2)
plt = ggplot(df, aes(x = scores, y = times1, color = factor(groups)))
plt = plt + geom_point(cex = 4) + geom_line() + theme_bw() 
plt = plt + geom_point(aes(x = scores, y=times2),pch = 23, cex =4)+ geom_line(aes(x = scores, y=times2))
plt = plt + facet_wrap(~ groups, ncol = 4, scales = "free_x") 
plt
```

which results in

[image]

How can I add a guide for the diamond points, and how can I change the title of each of the corresponding guides.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a legend for something, it should be specified as an aesthetic. Perhaps something like

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = scores, color = factor(groups))) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=times1, shape="times1"), cex = 4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=times1)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=times2, shape="times2"),cex =4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=times2)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ groups, ncol = 4, scales = "free_x") + theme_bw()
```

Rather than mannally adding layers, it would be even better if you properly rehaped your data to a format that ggplot perfers

```
ggplot(reshape2::melt(df, id=c("groups","scores")), 
    aes(x=scores,y=value, shape=variable, color=factor(groups))) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~groups)
```

Comment: is it possible to remove the circles from the groups guide and just keep the colors and the lines?

Comment: Just drop the geom_point() argument - note that ggplot layers different plot elements on top of each other - geom_line delivers the lines, geom_point the points (shapes) - both inherit their coloring from the base layer aesthetics

Comment: @CMichael I am familiar with what you are saying, but I cannot just drop the geom_point for the reason that I still need the guide for the points.